# C++ if/else statement problems

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, if-statement

I was using xcode the other day, and was working on a text-based conversation game-thingy.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Conversation simulator requires you to type in all caps for all  of your replies"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Type your first and last name!"<<std::endl;
    std::string fname = " ";
    std::string lname = " ";
    bool samename = false;
    std::cin>> fname >> lname ;
    if  (fname == "MUSCLE" and lname == "MAN")
        std::cout<< "Wow, we have the same first and last name!"<<std::endl;
        samename = true;
    else
        std::cout<< fname << " "<< lname << "is a very nice name"<<std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

nothing seems quite wrong to me, but Xcode won't run because on this line:

```
else
```

it expected an expression? I can't think of what that might mean.

Comment: Indentation does not scoping make.

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered my question.

Comment: Don't you just hate it when that happens. Good IDE's don't mess up indentation like that but it can happen.

Answer (score 9):

You need braces if you wish to execute more than one statement under `if`. Here is a fix that compiles for me.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout<<"Conversation simulator requires you to type in all caps for all  of your replies"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Type your first and last name!"<<std::endl;
        std::string fname = " ";
        std::string lname = " ";
        bool samename = false;
        std::cin>> fname >> lname;
        if  (fname == "MUSCLE" and lname == "MAN") {
                std::cout<< "Wow, we have the same first and last name!"<<std::endl;
                samename = true;
        } else {
                std::cout<< fname << " "<< lname << "is a very nice name"<<std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need of writing `std` everywhere. Write `using namespace std;` below the headers.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the curly braces for the if-block:

```
if  (fname == "MUSCLE" and lname == "MAN") {
    std::cout<< "Wow, we have the same first and last name!"<<std::endl;
    samename = true;
}
else
    std::cout<< fname << " "<< lname << "is a very nice name"<<std::endl;
```

Without them, only the very next statement (the output in your case) belongs to the `if`. So setting the flag in the next line renders the `else` incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot brackets in your `if` .. `else` statement below are the fixes.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Conversation simulator requires you to type in all caps for all  of your replies"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Type your first and last name!"<<std::endl;
    std::string fname = " ";
    std::string lname = " ";
    bool samename = false;
    std::cin>> fname >> lname ;
    if  (fname == "MUSCLE" and lname == "MAN"){
        std::cout<< "Wow, we have the same first and last name!"<<std::endl;
        samename = true;
    } else {
        std::cout<< fname << " "<< lname << "is a very nice name"<<std::endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss parenthesis:

```
If () {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe one must use the Open-Close curly braces:

```
if  (fname == "MUSCLE" and lname == "MAN")
{
    std::cout<< "Wow, we have the same first and last name!"<<std::endl;
    samename = true;
}
else
    std::cout<< fname << " "<< lname << "is a very nice name"<<std::endl;
```